# AS3: Farther-running ray hit test with 3D triangle

Tags: actionscript-3, geometry, raytracing, hittest

I have a 3D triangle defined by three `Vector3D` instances. And I have a ray that shoots from (x, y, 0) (depth value is always 0) and goes farther (the depth value becomes larger). How can I know:

1. Whether the ray hits the triangle at somewhere?
2. If yes, where do they hit?

Thanks.

Comment: Umm, This is what I need to perform ray-casting, and I have only been reading several sources, and I haven't written any actual code since I HAVE NO IDEA. So I can't provide you with codes, but if you want a source that I read about, here are some of them:

http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/raycast/

http://blog.andre-michelle.com/2005/as3-raycaster/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raycasting

Comment: I think the idea of SO is that you try something first, then post a question here if you don't succeed. I don't think you'll get many replies asking for a general tutorial. As a start, you might look into http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestPoint%28%29

Comment: That's your theory anyway, and thanks for the Adobe Reference. I haven't stated clearly in the question, I do not want to use DisplayObject and anything like that. I accept math and formulas and all that, though. Anyway I will try the code and edit the question again with the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Check here for solution http://www.softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0105/algorithm_0105.htm#intersect_RayTriangle()